# difference between acf() from {stats} and Acf() from {forecast}

Tags: r, autocorrelation

When I execute both functions on the same vector, I get slightly different graphs. I think I know what is happening but I want to confirm. acf() shows the spike at lag 0 which is 1 naturally, this makes the rest of the graph look much smaller. Acf() in contrast does not show the spike at lag 0 and starts at lag 1. Am I right in my assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is actually explained in the [`forecast` package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html):

> The functions improve the acf, pacf and ccf functions. The main
>   differences are that Acf does not plot a spike at lag 0 when
>   type=="correlation" (which is redundant) and the horizontal axes show
>   lags in time units rather than seasonal units.